# Is there some sort of ffmpeg output conversion to ffmpeg commandline?

Tags: ffmpeg

Say we have many video records that we want merge with -vcodec copy (or equivalent syntax). Without reencoding, without loss of quality. And few records (minor set), with another codecs, parameters and so on. So we can use ffprobe for file, that represent majority of sources. We get lot of information.

But can we get here commandline hints for ffmpeg, that could be used to convert another (not yet "compatible") files to this same format? At least for one selected stream of "master" file, for example.

Question is not about some scpecific output codec and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exsitsing tool to to this. You would need to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Each video stream inside a video file can only include same codec. So I recommend you to at first step, merge files with same codec with `-vcodec copy`. The check if which codec is mostly available in your merged files (e.g. CodecA). At second step, convert other merged files with other codecs to CodecA. Finally, merge all files (which all have now CodecA) with `-vcodec copy`.

Please keep in mind that if the video files are in different sizes, you have to reencode them.